# Xcode LaunchScreen image position changes

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, splash-screen

I'm working on flutter app and trying to add ios LaunchScreen I have very simple LaunchScreen layout. Green background and image bottom center. Image is added to assets.

UIImageView has width, height, centerX and bottomSpace constraint. That's what I see in XCode.

[image: Xcode]

On start, launch screen works fine:

[image: Correct mode]

After 1-2 seconds, launch screen changes layout and image jumps on top.

[image: incorrect mode]

I've tried:

- restart xcode
- clean build folder
- restart iPhone
- remove app from iPhone
- combinations of previous steps.

What should I change to prevent launch screen layout change?

Comment: I got the exact same problem. Did you fix it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try this way

1. set logo bottom constraint.
2. set logo leading and trailing constraint.
3. set logo width and height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This worked for me on xcode launchScreen editor:

**Change Vertical space constraints from Top/Bottom Layout Guide to    Superview**